# Correct way to raise an exception in an ASP.NET MVC 4 ActionFilterAttribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

Note that this is for an ApiController in MVC 4 although I think it shouldn't change anything.

```
 public class OAuthFilter : System.Web.Http.ActionFilterAttribute
 {
       public override void OnActionExecuting(System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionContext actionContext)
       {
              if (checkVerified())
              {
                   // How to raise a 401 or some other type of exception.
              }
       }        
 }
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can set the result property of the `HttpActionContext`:

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
{
    if (checkVerified())
    {
        actionContext.Response = 
            new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
    }
}
```

you may probably just throw:

```
throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
```

but I haven't checked that one.

Comment: Throwing `HttpResponseException` does **not** work, because it's in Web API, not MVC. Therefore, it will be treated by MVC as any unhandled exception resulting in a HTTP 500.

Comment: In MVC you can use `return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);` within an Action